# How to pass arguments to external Javascript files?

Tags: javascript

So on W3Schools they show this example:

```
<p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
    }
</script>
```

If I had an external JS File called myJSFile.js and all it had was

```
 function myFunction(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
 }
```

and I wanted to pass the ID "demo" from the HTML into the .js file how would I do it? I know you start with

```
 <script src = "myJSFile.js></script>
```

but I don't know how to call the myFunction function and pass an argument into it.

To be extra clear I want to do something like

```
<head>
    <script src = "myJSFile.js></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <p id = "demo></demo>
    myFunction("demo")
</body>
```

Comment: When you use script tags to load a javascript file they are loaded on your page. You can access any top level objects/variables from them directly, so just `myFunction(whateverID)`

Comment: The question has a duplicate, but is this the right one? The question here is actually how to call the javascript function with argument from HTML?

Comment: I'm trying to do myFunction(whateverID) but nothing is happening.

Comment: You need to call the function either in a script tag in the body part, or in event handler that is attached to DOM element. Try <script>myFunction("demo")</script>

Comment: It turns out I don't need the src when I call the function in the body and that was the entire problem. I am ashamed.